# How to un-enrage a wave in GemCraft: Chasing Shadows?

Tags: gemcraft-chasing-shadows

I accidentally enraged a wave that I didn't want to enrage. Is there any way to undo this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Steam v.1.0.4 release notes](http://gameinabottle.com/blog/2015/06/gccs-kongregate-release-steam-v-1-0-4-ag-v-1-1-14/):

> New features/changes:
>
> - Press delete over a wave stone to remove enraging

So, to un-enrage a wave, press <kbd>Delete</kbd> with mouse over the wave stone you want to un-enrage. This will erase all gems bombs dropped on that wave stone. The mana you spent on enraging the wave will *not* be restored.